# Java 2D array sum (addition of all)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to sum a 2D array to this:

I want the method to sum a 2D array. However, if `x` is greater than `y` the program gets an exception. I tried to debug it, but I do not know how to fix it smoothly. Should I create another method if `x` is greater than `y`? `Points` is the array with all the values.

```
 int x = //Random value
 int y = //Random value
 deltSum = new int[y];

 int output = 0;
 for (int t = 0; t < x; t++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        output += points[t][i]; //Add all values in the first section of the array.
    }
    deltSum[t] = output;
    System.out.println(output);
    output = 0;
 }
```

Comment: What exception do you get? ArrayIndexOutOfBound?

Comment: @SMA I ran the code and it is an ArrayIndexOutOfBound.

Comment: @Ainvox this means OP need to set proper value for x and y.

Comment: @SMA Which I did? I guess...

Comment: @Mr.Robot random values are fine as long as its within the boundary limit of your 2D array.

Comment: Is it a sum of array elements or is it something much more tricky? Why "random" sized? Consider closing as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign values of `x` and `y` as below:

```
int x = points.length;
int y = points[].length;
deltSum = new int[y];
```

Understand that if the Random values are out of the index of `point[][]` array, then it will surely give you runtime exceptions.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, this cannot the solution. OP says those values are random, thus they cannot be set to a constant value.

Comment: Yes, but if these "random" values are outside the size of array, the whole question does not make make much sense.

Comment: @h22 we can give a range to those "random" values so that they do not go beyond the size of array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want random values then use [`Random Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) within the range of length of the array to get different and random values of `x` and `y` and avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception.

```
import java.util.Random; //to use Random Class...

...

Random randomGenerator = new Random(); //making instance of Random

//these statements will assign a value to x & y that is random 
//and smaller than the maximum length which is specified.
int x = randomGenerator.nextInt(points.length); //Will assign random value to x less then points.length
int y = randomGenerator.nextInt(points[0].length); ////Will assign random value to x less then points[].length
```